# Share SharePoint site documents with external users

Tags: sharepoint-online, external-users

So, I know there is a way to share 'regular' folders and files with external users without sign-in.

Is there a way to do this with sites? 
For example, I have a site: https://mycompany.sharepoint.com/sites/NameOfSite
and on that site I have folders and files:  https://mycompany.sharepoint.com/sites/NameOfSite/Documents/Folder/SubFolder/file.pdf

Is there a way I can allow everyone with the above link to access 'file.pdf' without having to sign in?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

@Balakishnan is slightly of, since you asked for an option to share "without the need to sign in"

You actually posted 2 Objects in your question. Since a different answer applies to both of them ill try to lay it out.

For files and folder you have the ability to generate anonymous access links. These links contain a access token in them and allow the user with the link to access the files in question. They can also expire after a certain amount (or your admin can force an expiration)

Here is an example for such a link, which I invalidated by XXX my tenant:
https://XXXXXXXX.sharepoint.com/:f:/g/EgA412_LNJFLldn8LXnv2PwBGM0Hm9GCVRJRLrYdNHOQVg?e=Eo49Im

For the site collection itself you do not have the option to using these links. Here you need to grant access to real ppl. You can look them up in your AAD or even invite external ones (If it is allowed by your Admin again)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can share the document from a specific document library in the Site.
 Assuming that external access is enabled for the site you can create a new group or add to a security group specific external user with required permission

Please check for more info [Microsoft](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Microsoft-OneDrive-Blog/Introducing-a-new-secure-external-sharing-experience/ba-p/112624)

Regards,
Balakrishnan